# Define a list variable in azure devops pipeline on runtime

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an azure pipeline YAML file and I can't figure out how to declare a list variable in a script and use it on the next step.

What I would like is something like that:

```
- script: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=packages]@('a','b')"
  
- template: publish-template.yml
  parameters:
    packages: packages
```

or

```
- script: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=packages]@('a','b')"
  
- ${{ each package in parameters.packages }}:
  - script: echo ${{ package }}
```

But I can't find out how it's possible.

Thanks :)

Comment: You are trying to mix macro variables (which are set at runtime) with expressions (which are expanded during pipeline parsing) - essentially you cannot do this.

Comment: Hi @Or Gaizer, Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if you have any questions. If the answer could help, you may consider accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do such thing. Variables are kept as strings. So this `script: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=packages]@('a','b')"` will produce a string `('a','b')` and not an array. You can parse is script task and treat as array but there is no way to have array served at to level as you show in your example.

Please check it [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/812728/variables-in-yaml-pipeline-are-not-allowing-to-def.html):

> Yaml variables have always been string: string mappings. The doc appears to be currently correct, though we may have had a bug when last you visited.

We are preparing to release a feature in the near future to allow you to pass more complex structures. Stay tuned!

Comment: Any news around that? I would love to add a dropdown menu that is generated from a script or a task. Then the values would be available for user to select it and then run the pipeline